# Express App on Azure cannot load static file, status 500

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying an Node.js Express App on Azure and the app failed to load static css/js file. The static file works fine under my localhost:3000. But when running on Azure, it throw out Internal Server Error 500.

The error in my chrome looks like:

GET https:///resources/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error). The directory tree for this css file is /public/resources/css

I assume that my static file path is correct, otherwise I would see a 404 error instead of 500

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I checked the DetailedErrors log files from Azure Diagnostic Tool. And it was showing the 500 error was due to the following:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
D:\Python34\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

In fact, in my Azure App Service application setting, I turn on the python 3.4 version and which somehow azure trying to handle my static request using python. I simply turn off the python version in my application setting and now I can successfully load my static file.

Comment: Hi, you can mark your answer to help other people who meet the similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Per my experience, I think the incorrect deployment cause the error code `500` of Internal Server Error in Node.js on Azure. So to fix it, please first check the content of your `web.config` file in the path `site/wwwroot`. And there is a standard sample `web.config` from Kudu wiki page [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) which you can refer to.

If your Node app deployed successed, you will see a `404 Not Found` error code for a non-exist static file instead of `500` as you said.

However, there is a difference for the variable `__dirname` between local and Azure. On local, the value of `__dirname` variable is always the full path name where you start up a node process, such as print `__dirname` will return `D:\home` if run `node` in CMD at `D:\home`. But on Azure, you will see the `__dirname` value in any path which be `.` if you try to run the command `node -e "const path = require('path'); console.log(__dirname);"` in the Kudu console, as the figure below.

[image]

Therefore, the `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` value is always `public` which not be related to the current path of node started up by IIS. So to fix it, please use an absolute path like `D:\home\site\wwwroot` instead of `__dirname` variable in `path.join` method or just directly use `D:\home\site\wwwroot\public` in `express.static` method.